# How to solve "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error."

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, usb-drive

In Ubuntu 22.04 I can't open/mount any hard drive or USB flash on my computer.

The error when I try to mount via command line:

```
➜  ~ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/mahdi -t ext4   
mount: /media/mahdi: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Here is the error when I open it with file explorer:

[image]

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Did you ever make a filesystem (mkfs) on that partition? If not, maybe there's no filesystem on the USB, so no mount is possible. Did you ever have any files on the device?  Don't run mkfs if you have data you want to preserve.

Comment: I think I didn't make a filesystem (mkfs) on this partition. my computer doesn't mount a USB flash or any hard drive. But the same flash and hard drive work on another computer.  My data on the hard drive is Important but not in USB flash.